# ¿Se puede cambiar la descripción en plena ejecución de una barra de progreso?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter, progressbar, ipython

Tengo una barra de progreso, y quería saber si se puede modificar la descripción una vez que ya esta en ejecución.
El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
from ipywidgets import IntProgress
from IPython.display import display
import time

test = IntProgress(min=0, max=10,description='Loading:',bar_style='warning',)    
display(test)
count=0
hojas = 3
capitulos = 5

for b in range(capitulos):
    for i in range(hojas):
        test.value +=1
        print("Capitulo: "+str(b+1) + " Hoja: "+str(i+1))
        time.sleep(0.1)
        count+=1
```

output:

```
Loading: :::::::::::::::::
Capitulo: 1 Hoja: 1
Capitulo: 1 Hoja: 2
Capitulo: 1 Hoja: 3
Capitulo: 2 Hoja: 1
Capitulo: 2 Hoja: 2
Capitulo: 2 Hoja: 3
Capitulo: 3 Hoja: 1
Capitulo: 3 Hoja: 2
Capitulo: 3 Hoja: 3
Capitulo: 4 Hoja: 1
Capitulo: 4 Hoja: 2
Capitulo: 4 Hoja: 3
Capitulo: 5 Hoja: 1
Capitulo: 5 Hoja: 2
Capitulo: 5 Hoja: 3
```

Mi idea sería mostrar:

```
Loading hoja 1 de capitulo 1 ::::::::::::
```

"y de esa manera iterar cada hoja y cada capitulo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo tienes que modificar el atributo `description` en el ciclo. No obstante, debes evitar que el texto se corte cuando sea largo como es tu caso:

```
import time
from ipywidgets import IntProgress
from IPython.display import display


count = 0
hojas = 3
capitulos = 5

style = {'description_width': 'initial'}
test = IntProgress(style=style,
                   min=0,
                   max=hojas * capitulos,
                   description="Iniciando...",
                   bar_style='warning'
                   )    
display(test)

for b in range(capitulos):
    for i in range(hojas):
        test.value += 1
        test.description = f"Capitulo: {b + 1} Hoja: {i + 1}"
        time.sleep(0.5)

test.description = "Completado"
```

Otra opción es usar un `Label` junto a la barra dentro de un layout horizontal, lo cual no reducirá el tamaño de la barra al aumentar el tamaño de la descripción:

```
import time
from ipywidgets import HBox, Label, IntProgress
from IPython.display import display

count = 0
hojas = 3
capitulos = 5

pb_cont = HBox(width='100%')
test = IntProgress(style=style,
                   description="",
                   min=0,
                   max=hojas * capitulos,
                   bar_style='warning'
                   )    
label = Label('Iniciando...')
pb_cont.children = [label, test]
display(pb_cont)

for b in range(capitulos):
    for i in range(hojas):
        test.value += 1
        label.value = f"Capitulo: {b + 1} Hoja: {i + 1}"
        time.sleep(0.5)

label.value = "Completado"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]